# How do I upload a file with the remote file destination as part of the URL?

Tags: ruby

I have the following method for uploading files:

```
def send_to_ftp(sourcefile,host,port,username,password,log_path)
  begin
    ftp =Net::FTP.new
    ftp.connect(host, port)
    ftp.passive = true
    ftp.login(username, password)
    ftp.chdir(host)
    ftp.putbinaryfile(sourcefile)
    ftp.close
    return true
  rescue Exception => err
    puts err.message
    return false
  end
end
```

When I enter the URL as `hostname.com/path/to/ftpupload`,  I get an error: "name or service not known". However, if I enter only "hostname.com" as the host it works but it means there's no way of determining where to put the file on the ftp server

Comment: We need clarification. What is the exact error, and what line causes it. Also, you don't show how you are determining the file to read. You say you "enter the URL" but don't show how you call the method. Is URL supposed to be determined from `sourcefile`? If so, where do you parse that information out? No language would be able to magically determine this, so  that has to be calculated some place.

Comment: I've said the error as part of the post. Also about the url just assume am calling the method with hostname.com/path/to/ftpupload as the host parameter. The rest is clear.

Comment: You said the error, but NOT the line, which is important for people to see. *I* know what line it is, but others who are reading your question in search of an answer will probably not know. Also, when you create a question, it's really important to show your input data or method call, and be as clear as possible when explaining the problem. Those of us answering questions are working with limited amounts of time. The more you tell us that is pertinent to the question, the better we can help you.

Comment: theTinMan said exactly right! **Save our times,in return will give you better answers as much as possible.** :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the same argument to `FTP#connect` and `FTP#chdir`. They actually need separate parts of the full URL, namely domain name and path. Try the following:

```
domain, dir = host.split('/', 2)
#...
ftp.connect(domain, port) # domain = 'hostname.com'
#...
ftp.chdir(dir) # dir = 'path/to/ftpupload'
```

Comment: cabron: your code works if modify as follows: ftp.chdir(dir) should be changed to ftp.chdir("/#{dir}").

Answer (score 3):

The `host` parameter for `connect` can't be "hostname.com/path/to/ftpupload". Per the documentation, it:

> Establishes an FTP connection to host...

and a "host" would be "hostname.com", so you need to split that string into the components necessary.

I'd take advantage of Ruby's URI class and pass in a full URL:

```
ftp://hostname.com/path/to/ftpupload
```

Letting URI parse that makes it easy to grab sections from it:

```
require 'uri'
uri = URI.parse('ftp://hostname.com/path/to/ftpupload')
uri.host
# => "hostname.com"
uri.path
# => "path/to/ftpupload"
```

Here's how I'd write it:

```
require 'uri'

def send_to_ftp(sourcefile, host, username, password, log_path)
  uri = URI.parse('ftp://' + host)

  ftp = Net::FTP.new
  ftp.connect(uri.host, uri.port)
  ftp.passive = true
  ftp.login(username, password)
  ftp.chdir(uri.path)
  ftp.putbinaryfile(sourcefile)
  ftp.close

  true

rescue Exception => err
  puts err.message
  false
end
```

With two more changes you can simplify the code even more. Change the method definition to:

```
def send_to_ftp(sourcefile, host, log_path)
```

and:

```
  ftp.login(uri.user, uri.password)
```

allows you to call the code using a URL with the embedded username and password:

```
username:password@hostname.com/path/to/ftpupload
```

which is a standard way of calling an internet resource with the userid and password contained in it.

At that point you're left with:

```
require 'uri'

def send_to_ftp(sourcefile, host, log_path)
  uri = URI.parse('ftp://' + host)

  ftp = Net::FTP.new
  ftp.connect(uri.host, uri.port)
  ftp.passive = true
  ftp.login(uri.user, uri.password)
  ftp.chdir(uri.path)
  ftp.putbinaryfile(sourcefile)
  ftp.close

  true

rescue Exception => err
  puts err.message
  false
end
```

and your method call looks like:

```
send_to_ftp(
  'path/to/source/file', 
  'username:password@hostname.com/path/to/ftpupload', 
  log_path
)
```

Comment: Could you tell me what are the standard libraries I need to `include` except `uri`?

Comment: Thanks! `+1` to you... one of my beloved answerer.. in *SO*